# iOS Facebook login button with swift

Tags: ios, facebook-login, swift3

Just wondering what i'm doing wrong with the code below, the code inside the block facebookLogin.login(withReadPermissions:) never gets called.

```
  @IBAction func fbBtnPressed(sender: UIButton!) {
    let facebookLogin =  FBSDKLoginManager()

    facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: [ "email" ], from: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, facebookError:NSError?) in

        if facebookError != nil {
            print("Facebook login failed. Error \(facebookError)")
        } else {
            let accessToken = FBSDKAccessToken.current().tokenString
            print("Successfully logged in with facebook. \(accessToken)")
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: is the connection to the button correct? Does the button function get called at all?

Comment: yes, the button func gets called.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `facebookLogin` is being deallocated when it goes out of scope at the end of the function call, before it has had time to complete.

Try move `let facebookLogin = FBSDKLoginManager()` into the containing (class) scope:

```
let facebookLogin =  FBSDKLoginManager()

@IBAction func fbBtnPressed(sender: UIButton!) {

    facebookLogin.logIn(withReadPermissions: [ "email" ], from: self) { (facebookResult: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult?, facebookError:NSError?) in

        // ...    
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the token existed when you ask for the permission? As stated in [Facebook Login SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/permissions),

> You should check the for availability of an existing token before you call the loginManager.

Else you would need to set the permission to your login button with `self.facebookLogInButton.readPermissions = ["email"]` as stated at the permission page I linked